# Overloading Operator = as a member function

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

C++ allows to overload `=` operator only as a member function not as a global function.

Bruce Eckel says that `if it was possible to define operator= globally, then you might attempt to redefine the built-in = sign.` and due to this reason you can overload = operator only as a member function.

if C++ has already defined `=` operator then why the other operators like `+` `-` etc... are not defined by C++ as they can be overloaded as a non-member function.  ?

Comment: The semantics of `=` are (usually) obvious. The semantics of the others are not -- what would `-` do for e.g. `std::string`?

Comment: Many many duplicates on this one, let me find one...

Comment: that means only operator `=` is predefined by C++...is it so?

Comment: The *copy* assignment operator is automatically declared and defined if needed by the compiler.

Comment: That rationale seems to be wrong (or at least very ambiguous). Yes, with operator overloading in general you could attempt to redefine built-in operators, just that the compiler won't let you.

Comment: Are you asking this out of pure curiosity, or is there something specific you need to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler generates a default copy assignment operator (operator=) for all classes that do not define their own. That means that a global overload won't be selected under any circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator (when used as initialization) is deeply tied to constructors; when you code `SomeClass a = b;` some constructor of `SomeClass` is called.

Comment: How? Initialization and assignment are two completely different things.

Comment: I agree, but when you code `SomeClass a = b;` a constructor is involved (and the syntax don't show that).

Comment: I think it would be better to say "a single equals sign" because `SomeClass a = b;` isn't using the assignment operator, though you do use the equals sign

Comment: Agreed. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Basile : Your edit is backwards -- `=` when used as _initialization_ is deeply tied to constructors; when used as assignment it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Because assignment has a clear meaning for any type, the other operators do not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it would be really hard to implement an operator=() from outside the class without reference to the specific implementation and the private members.

Operators like '+', however, sometimes have to be defined at the global level. Consider a complex number class. I can define complex::operator+(float) from inside my class, but I *must* define operator+(float, complex) from outside because the first operand doesn't have the type of my class.

**Edit**: I should have mentioned also that it's often easy to define global operators like operator+ without reference to specific implementation details by using other operators defined in the class. For example:

```
complex operator+(float lhs, complex rhs) {return complex(lhs, 0)+rhs;}
```

Comment: A common way to implement it is copy-and-swap idiom. No special access needed.

Comment: And global `operator+` is commonly implemented in terms of member `+=` :) `complex operator+(complex a, const complex& b) { return a += b; }`

Comment: The big difference here is that `operator+` is producing a temporary of whatever type you like, independently of the type of `lhs`. `=` is assignment (or initialization), returning a reference to the written-to field, and the equivalent to `lhs` must be the same base type as the return value, or you'd be dereferencing the return incorrectly. At that point, what can you do with a global overload of `=` that can't be done with class-defined type conversion operators and `operator=`?

Answer (score 0):

To expand @ildjarn's comment, the semantics of the global built-in `=` are universally set; it is called when initializing a new instance of a class with an rvalue of some kind, and calls the appropriate constructor (based on the compile-time type of the rvalue), which is a nice way of providing c-style initialization instead of strictly requiring all variables to be initialized by an explicit call to a constructor. Overloading the global operator would change too much of the underlying semantics of the language while providing little to know real benefit--you'd be fundamentally changing how, which, and whether constructors are called, and if you feel like you have a reason to do that through overloading the global `=`, there's a good chance you're wrong.

The class-member `operator=` is overloadable because it's operating on an already existing and initialized lvalue of its class, and there are obvious cases where you would want custom behavior in modifying a pre-existing object (like only copying certain members from the rvalue while recalculating others and leaving still others alone, or properly disposing of resources held by pointer to take hold of a new resource without leaking memory).

Where the member `operator=` deals with a complete lvalue object, the built-in starts with nothing but an appropriately sized block of memory and an rvalue. **Constructors of all shapes and forms are the language-provided interfaces for modifying the behavior of the built-in `=` without ceding control of the semantics themselves to you.** I'd be interested to see what you feel you need to accomplish by overloading global `=` that couldn't be done with a constructor.

Comment: Initialization and assignment are two completely different things.

Comment: When will the global `=` operator be called with an existing object as an lvalue? I can't think of a case where assignment wouldn't happen through the member `operator=`, regardless of whether it's user-defined or compiler-synthesized? EDIT: Well, the built-in types  call a built-in `=`, but again, your interface to that operation is the type conversion operators, like `operator int()`. You don't modify integer assignment, you just describe how to coalesce your new type to `int`.

Comment: And that interface holds for any assignment to a type you're not defining. If you have access to the type you want to assign your new type to, you can write an `ExistingType::operator=(NewType&)` method. If you don't, you can write an `NewType::operator ExistingType()` method. What would changing the global built-in `=` do that overloading one or both of these member methods couldn't? Either way, you're going to end up storing an `ExistingType`, and I can't see how changing that semantic would make sense.